# Odds calculation when drawing 3 cards.

Tags: probability, card-games, gambling

I would like some feedback on some of my thinking.

Situation : I pull 3 cards consecutively from a standard 52 deck.

**Question 1** : What are the odds of pulling a flush? (all same suit).

i am trying to break it down as simple as i possibly can, my attempt :

Add up all the hearts wich comes up to 13..
So the chance of pulling a flush of hearts becomes:
(13/52) * (12/51) * (11/50) =1.29% chance
i have 4 suits, so 1,29% *4 = 5.16% chance to pull a flush..

**Question 2** : What are the odds of pulling a straight?
I use the same logic as above
How do i make a straight?
A-2-3 , 2-3-4 ,.... J-Q-K

the suit doesn't matter so i can mix any suit. so my math would look like this :
TAO = Total amount of

((TAO Aces /52) * (TAO 2's / 51) * (TAO 3's/50)) * 6

the *6 is for the amount of possibilities i can draw the 3 cards.
Do this all the way to J-Q-K

((TAO Jacks /52) * (TAO Queens / 51) * (TAO Kings / 50))* 6.

Add these all up to get your total chance for a straight : 3.19% chance
Wich from all data i've found is wrong.

**Question 3**
This is probably the hardest question to answer.
I want to calculate the chance of a straight flush.
I believe i have 2 ways to calculate this
Option 1 : i do the math like above , and end up with a 0.199910% chance to get a royal flush
Option 2 : i know the chance of a flush and a straight, and multiply them to come up with the chance for bother events to occure.
in my case that would be   0.0516 * 0.0319 = 0.00164604 = 0.164604% chance to draw a royal flush.

It bothers me so much that i can't seem to figure this out.
I would love it if some would calmly explain what i'm doing wrong in each question.
Please give me some feedback asap :)

Yours sincerely
DImitri

Comment: Inquestion 3, your option 2 is wrong because straights and flushes are not independent

Comment: Doesn't Q-K-A count as a straight?

Comment: Also, I assume a three card royal flush is  only J-Q-K of the same suit. Is that correct?

Comment: i believe 2 is off for the reason WW1 gave... i am not sure if Q-K-A counts as a straight, in my math i didn't count it

Comment: @WW1 - yes , a royal flush is J-Q-K but i am asking about a STRAIGHT flush, i did wrongly name it in my question and adjusted it now :)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I think your code may be counting a pair of threes and a five as a straight, I think you should get $4^3 \times 11$ ( or 12 if you count Q-K-A) for the number of straights

Comment: @DimitriGevaert [Direct counting](https://tio.run/##TZBNjoMwDEb3nMJLu4OGMgzVCImTIFSlhRRL5EdJkOD0lLRT2pUty@99TuwSBqOLP@vWlZU1LgCH3gVjRp/Ic40ox8kPVT0KdekEzNXYa/R9QG6OLUjjgIE1zER1nVOKPjjBtyHsxFLhzkZu3hZjdULfelSst0n6LF/RvZmIsOEm/9AvLVG6ax4nbYsgdAevwAgmc934SWH@JvfXfF@NurAWgY32@B5bZ7rp@rrnl9JnkxdbYkHAEiQy0cMoo1Ge28Q61jHxv2k4K3@yMs/K4@H08Sktresd) shows that your 1,2 and 3.1 are all correct.

Comment: The third one should be $\frac{4\times  4\times 4\times 11}{52 \choose 3}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{52}3$ equally probable three card "hands"

1 - For each of 4 suits there are $\binom{13}3$ ways choosing card types

2 - Let's assume Q-K-A is a valid straight (if not, multiply my answers for 2. and 3. by $\frac{11}{12}$

There are 12 ways have a straight with $4^3$ ways to choose the suits

3 - There are 12 ways have a straight with 4 ways to choose the suits when we require a straight flush

So 1: $$\frac{4\times \binom{13}3}{\binom{52}3}= 5.176\%$$

2:$$ \frac{12\times 4^3 }{\binom{52}3}= 3.475\%$$

3:$$ \frac{12*4 }{\binom{52}3}= 0.217\%$$

Comment: after changing my math , this checks out... Much appreciated !

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback , through your answers i managed to fix what was wrong :)